# Locating the dictionary within a list when inputting a specific value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

let us say we have a few clusters represented as dictionaries below:

```
cluster1 = {'Disks' : [0,1,2,3,12] , 'left': True , 'right': False}
cluster2 = {'Disks' : [3,4,5,2] , 'left':True ,'right': False }
cluster3 = {'Disks' : [6,7,8,2] , 'left':False ,'right': False }
cluster4 = {'Disks' : [10,11,12] , 'left':True, 'right':True  }

Listofclusters = [cluster1,cluster2,cluster3,cluster4]
```

Then I make a list of the clusters as above to store them....

If i want to search the list for a particular disk and would like it to tell me which clusters within the list have those disks 
how would i do that?

Comment: You could assign an `_id` field for each of the clusters if you want to identify it. Otherwise, you can just return the cluster without necessarily identifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement:

> to search the list for a particular disk and would like it to tell me
>   which clusters within the list have those disks

Use the following approach which will form a dict `cluster_numbers` which key is a ***disk number*** and value is a list of ***cluster names(cluster order numbers)***
Let's find all cluster names(numbers) which have one or more disk numbers from the following list `[2, 10, 7]`

```
search_disks = [2, 10, 7]
cluster_numbers = {d:[] for d in search_disks}

for d in cluster_numbers.keys():
    for k, c in enumerate(Listofclusters):
        if d in c['Disks']: cluster_numbers[d].extend(['cluster' + str(k+1)])

print(cluster_numbers)
```

The output:

```
{2: ['cluster1', 'cluster2', 'cluster3'], 10: ['cluster4'], 7: ['cluster3']}
```

Comment: beautiful it works better than i could have hoped for and does exactly what i wanted it to do!

Comment: would it be possible though to explain how this particular piece of code works?

Comment: `cluster_numbers ` is a prepared dict which keys are input disk numbers and values are empty lists that should be filled during further processing. Then, we are iterating through disk numbers which are presented by keys of our prepared list `cluster_numbers.keys()`. For each disk number, we should check the occurrence within each cluster disks list from the list of clusters `Listofclusters`. When the occurrence is found - the prepared dict `cluster_numbers ` will be extended with appropriate cluster number under current disk number `cluster_numbers[d].extend(['cluster' + str(k+1)])`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the data you have, this should do it:

```
def findClusters(n, clusters):
    answer = []
    for cluster in clusters:
        if n in cluster['Disks']:
            answer.append(cluster)
    return answer
```

Now, that's a linear algorithm. With a little preprocessing, you should be able to improve the runtime substantially:

```
def preprocess(clusters):
    """
    Given the list of clusters, return a dictionary that maps 
    Disk numbers to a list of clusters that have that disk
    """

    answer = {}
    for i,cluster in enumerate(clusters):
        for disk in cluster['Disks']
            if disk not in answer:
                answer[disk] = []
            answer[disk].append(i)

    return answer

def findClusters(preprocessedData, clusters, diskNum):
    answer = []
    for clusterid in preprocessedData[diskNum]:
        answer.append(clusters[clusterid])
    return answer
```

The preprocessing takes linear time, while the actual search takes constant time (to find the relevant clusters) and linear time (in the order of the number of clusters found) to create the list of the relevant clusters

Comment: `def findClusters(n, clusters): return [cluster for cluster in clusters if n in cluster['Disks']]` might be a bit faster. :) Would need to benchmark, though. Nice answer.

Comment: hat would not be necessarily faster - it is just harder to read , since the OP needs to understand the logic.

Comment: @erip: I'm actually working on a much faster solution with some preprocessing. Stand by!

Comment: @jsbueno I'm not sure a list comprehension is harder to read, but if you think it is, that's OK. Just a suggestion, of course. Take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: A "much faster" solution would use indexing the thing in dicitionary which keys would be disks - that would diminish the alogorithmic complexity. I trust your new solution will go in that direction - but pleae keep the simple linear search as well.

Comment: @jsbueno: you and I think alike. I posted the simpler solution first, and have been developing the solution you mentioned for the past few minutes - check it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you for example, you want to search for disk 10 you can do the following:

```
>>> [cluster for cluster in Listofclusters if 10 in cluster['Disks']]
... [{'Disks': [10, 11, 12], 'right': True, 'left': True}]
```